# Fatal error during executing android app

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Why the app gets unfortunately stopped ??

Error is :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.example.prateek.urbanityc.Bg.doInBackground(Bg.java:45)
 at com.example.prateek.urbanityc.Bg.doInBackground(Bg.java:24)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

The android code is :-

.java file

```
   package com.example.prateek.urbanityc;

   import android.content.DialogInterface;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.RadioButton;
   import android.widget.RadioGroup;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class choose_ngo extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    AsyncResponse {
    Button next, skip;
    TextView tv8;
    //String b;
    //GlobalVariable gb;
    String email, type1, type2;

RadioGroup rg;
String a,b;
GlobalVariable gb;
int selectedid;
RadioButton rbvalue;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_ngo);

    /*rg=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    selectedid = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    rbvalue = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedid);
    a=rbvalue.getText().toString();  */

    skip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
   // tv8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    gb = GlobalVariable.getSingleInstance();

}

public void verify(View view) {

    type1 = "store_ngo";
    type2 = "show_details";
    email = gb.getVariables().get("email");

    //Toast.makeText(this, email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    /*Toast.makeText(this, a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Bg backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this, this);
    backgroundWorker.delegate = this;
    backgroundWorker.execute(type1, email,a);
     */

    back();



        }

public void processFinish(String output) {


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(choose_ngo.this);
    builder.setTitle("Verify Details");
    builder.setMessage(output);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), thanku.class));
            finish();

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), verify_details.class));
            finish();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}

public void back()
{
    Bg Bg = new Bg(this, this);
    Bg.delegate = this;
    Bg.execute(type2, email);
}

public void skip(View view) {
    email = gb.getVariables().get("email");
    back();


}

public void store() {
    b = getIntent().getExtras().getString("email2");
}
 }
```

code for backgroundworker class

```
  package com.example.prateek.urbanityc;

  import android.app.AlertDialog;
  import android.app.ProgressDialog;
  import android.content.Context;
   import android.os.AsyncTask;
   import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.OutputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.net.URLEncoder;

 public class Bg extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

AsyncResponse delegate;

Bg(Context ctx, AsyncResponse delegate) {
    context = ctx;
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];

    String item_info_url = "http://urbanity.000webhostapp.com/item_typ.php";
    String show_info_url = "http://urbanity.000webhostapp.com/verify.php";



   if(type.equals("item_info")) {

        try {

            String email = params[1];
            String a = params[2];
            String b = params[3];
            String c = params[4];

            URL url = new URL(item_info_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data =
                    URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                            URLEncoder.encode("a", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(a, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                            URLEncoder.encode("b", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(b, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                            URLEncoder.encode("c", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(c, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    else if(type.equals("show_details")) {

        try {

            String email = params[1];

            URL url = new URL(show_info_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data =
                    URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
}


@Override

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    if(result!=null){
        delegate.processFinish(result); }
    //alertDialog.show();

}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
  }
```

.xml file

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/activity_choose_ngo"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
     android:paddingLeft="64dp"
     android:background="@drawable/giving"
     android:paddingRight="64dp"
     android:paddingTop="16dp"
     tools:context="com.example.prateek.urbanityc.choose_ngo">

    <Button
     android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="SKIP"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="skip"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="NGOs AVAILABLE "
    android:textSize="25dp"

    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#0000FF"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Gramiksha"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Pryatna"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AshaKiran"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton2"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Udan"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton3"
        />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="NEXT"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="verify"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<!-- <TextView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Skip"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="skip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />  -->

   </RelativeLayout>
```

php file

```
   <?php
   require "con1.php";

   $email=$_POST["email"];
    $contact='';
  $add='';
   //$c=$_POST["c"]; 

   require_once('con1.php') ;

   $sql = "SELECT u_contact,u_add FROM user where u_mail = '$email' ";

   if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
       {
     // Fetch one and one row
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
      {
         echo "Contact: ".$row[0];
         echo "                           ";
        echo "Address: ".$row[1];
        }
     }

    // mysqli_close($conn);

     ?>
```

The app is getting stop on clicking the skip button whereas it is running at all other clicks of buttons in app. I am not able to understand why is it happening i have done a lot of google to rectify the problem but i am unable to find the solution. So plzz help out me guys......

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection attacks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `nullPointerException` in your AsyncTask. Could you check you are sending non null type.

```
if(type.equals("item_info"))
```

should be

```
if(type!= null && type.equals("item_info"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running multiple Async task that's why you are getting this error. Run you async task like this

```
AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel(new YourAsyncTask());
```

Let me know if this solved your problem.

Comment: can you please tell me which gradle library for this because  AsyncTaskCompat class cannot be resolved in my app

Comment: please read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/os/AsyncTaskCompat.html